# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2

Tags: maven, deploy, build-error, weblogic

подскажите пожалуйста, произвожу деплой на weblogicservice, когда выполняю команду `Lifecycle -> deploy`, то выходит ошибка `BUILD FAILURE: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project weblogic_users_REST_v1: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]`

Искал в интернете, было мало предложений исправления ошибки которые в итоге так и не помогли(

[image: Вот описание ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В pom.xml отсутствует элемент repository внутри блока distributionManagement

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>ид репозитория</id>
        <url>урл репозитория</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Хотел бы уточнить, а где взять эти данные ид и урл репозитория?

Comment: ну вы же выполняете команду deploy, значит должны знать куда деплоите))) Может вам и не нужно деплоить? Деплой осуществляется в некий репозиторий релизов. Например в maven central или в корпоративный nexus.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!